# Add a subtitle to the Bootstrap 4 modal header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-modal

I am using a simple modal window, created from the Bootstrap's (4.4) [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/).

It includes a modal header div:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I would like to add a subtitle below the h5, but I have no idea how as the "modal-header" class defines this div as flex.

All my attempts ended with the content next to this h5 header.

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried ? You could `display:block` your subtitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy

flex-column

just add **flex-column** class on your modal header. but in this case you need to adjust your close button by position absolute, by making its parent relative.

```
<div class="modal-header flex-column position-relative">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close position-absolute" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="top: 10px;right: 10px;">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Check the working example as well.

```css
.close {
  top: 10px;right: 10px; 
}
.modal-header {padding-right: 30px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header flex-column position-relative">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1Modal title 1</h5>
<h5 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close position-absolute" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Atul, I came up with the "flex-column" solution just at the moment of your answer, but I didn't know how to place the close button :-) However there is still a small problem realted to the close button's absolute position you suggested. The long title can be hidden behind this absolutely positioned button (or the button behind it).

Comment: Fixed, check now, all you need to do is, just give padding righ to your modal-header, padding-right=width of close button

Comment: And if this helps you, don't forget to upvote and mark it as the right answer, if need anything else, please let me know, Happy to help

Comment: I had to make it `!important` as the bootstrap's class had priority, but it should work now. Thanks.